# Display Custom Properties in the Identity Management Grid and Edit views

Tags: abp

I have added a couple of Custom Properties to AppUser.  All is fine with regards to database update.

**Custom Properties Added**:

```
public static void ConfigureCustomUserProperties<TUser>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TUser> b) where TUser: class, IUser
{
    b.Property<string>(nameof(AppUser.SiteCode));
    b.Property<string>(nameof(AppUser.SiteName));
}
```

**Question:**

Now I'm look for a way to display my 2 new custom properties in the Identity Management Grid and Edit views.

Is this possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research into the packages used for this feature I can see the columns are hard coded so I don't expect to get any ability to see custom properties in the near future.